# Зачем WordPress веб-разработчику и что в нём надо учить?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Вижу, что во множестве вакансий востребован *WordPress*, для чего он нужен веб-разработчику? Все видеоуроки, которые нашёл, это создание блога на *WordPress*, зачем мне это в работе и что бы вы могли посоветовать конкретно выучить по нему?

Спасибо.

Comment: Такая ситуация с работодателями потому, что они устали постоянно разбираться в велосипедах, которые пишут новички. Стандартные решения уберегают от этого. Также Разработку на WP легче поддерживать без разработчика, т.е. его легче заменить или на каком-то этапе вообще уволить.

Comment: @ArcherGodson, в плане - я создам сайт на WP для компании на которую буду работать и меня уволят? xD

Comment: этот жестокий мир ))

Comment: @Horchynskyi в плане ЕСЛИ Вас уволят, то другой разработчик сможет дальше заниматься проектом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP нужен если для ваших решений не нужен уникальный функционал, а гораздо проще не начинать делать свою cms с нуля, а взять готовый проект с множеством готовых плагинов и тем.

На WP можно делать визитки, форумы, магазины, у него существует api, для доступа других приложений к его функционалу.

Нельзя сказать, что нужно учить, это зависит от тех задач, которые требуются на проекте.

Главные вещи которые следует уметь:

- Верстать шаблоны и правильно использовать wp теги для вывода данных из БД
- Изменять существующие или писать свои плагины PHP

Answer (score 15):

### Почему WordPress

На WordPress создано порядка [25% всех сайтов](https://martechtoday.com/wordpress-used-on-25-percent-of-all-websites-report-151115), существующих в сети Интернет. Среди сайтов, использующих CMS, WordPress имеет [доминирующее положение с 60%](https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/content_management) рынка. Ближайший конкурент Joomla имеет в 9 раз меньшую долю присутствия.

На WordPress можно создавать не только визитки. Многие [всемирно известные мировые бренды используют WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/40-most-notable-big-name-brands-that-are-using-wordpress/) для своих сложных корпоративных сайтов. Среди них: [Mercedes-Benz](https://www.mercedes-benz.com/en/), The New Yorker, BBC America, Bloomberg Professional, Sony Music, MTV News, The Rolling Stones, SAP News Center и другие.

Интернет-магазин WooCommerce, созданный как плагин для WordPress, занимает [первое место среди систем электронной торговли](https://trends.builtwith.com/shop) (12%), ну или, можно сказать, делит 1-2 места с Magento (11%).

### Зачем WordPress веб-разработчику

Во-первых, без работы не останетесь. Во-вторых, заказчик предпочитает иметь дело с известной CMS, чтобы не быть зависимым от разработчика всю оставшуюся жизнь его веб-сайта.

### Что учить в WordPress

WordPress построен на [системе иерархии шаблонов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) и [широком использовании фильтров и хуков](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6680/kak-rabotayut-huki-v-wordpress-filtry-i-sobytiya.html). Начать, вероятно, надо с этого. Кроме того, надо понимать механизмы [создания собственных тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC) и [кастомизации имеющихся тем посредством дочерних](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), [написания собственных плагинов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Если вы работает в команде (да и вообще, как правило хорошего тона), то нужно создавать код согласно [стандартам кодирования WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_WordPress). В этом вам поможет современная среда разработки, например, [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) с [анализаторами кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737379/220220) и отладчиком.

WordPress снабжен всеобъемлющей документацией на русском языке. Практически на любой вопрос можно получить ответ на русском языке на этих двух ресурсах: [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) и [kama](https://wp-kama.ru/).

**UPDATE**

Из комментария @SeVlad:

Основа основ WordPress - это [цикл по постам](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress).

Новый Codex [здесь](http://developer.wordpress.org/). Пока не полный и без локализации, но старый местами уже устарел.

WordPress позволяет создавать не только записи (post), страницы (page), но и [кастомные типы записей](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), с помощью которых можно представить практически любые сущности, необходимые при разработке сайта: акции, шаблоны, проекты и т.п.

Comment: Люто плюсую! Но парочку добавок, думаю стоит добавить в ответ:. Во первых основа ВП -  это цикл https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress. А второе - новый кодекс тут: http://developer.wordpress.org/ пока не полный и без локализации, но старый местами уже устарел. А этот ответ будет полезен и через неск. лет.
Да можно ещё добавить про кастомные типы, таксономии и поля.

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо, дополню ответ.