# Интернет магазин на CMS + Android REST API

Tags: android, wordpress, joomla, cms, opencart

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность сделать Android API к интернет магазину, который собран на Open Cart, WordPress или какой либо другой CMS. CMS-ы предоставляют такую возможность в принципе или нет?

Comment: Для Opencart есть ввиде плагина. Вордпресс вообще-то не интернет магазин, но опять же с помощью плагинов у него строят (omg). Для такой сборной солянки вряди ли API есть. Плюс API сильно зависит от версии движка и кол-во методов разное. Так что лучше уж писать самому.

Answer (score 0):

На WordPress - конечно, можно. Интернет-магазин WooCommerce, созданный как плагин для WordPress, [занимает первое место в мире среди систем электронной торговли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/702220/220220) (12%). Естественно, при количестве активных установок более 1 миллиона, для WooCommerce все давно сделано и самым детальным образом документировано. Есть API, по которому можно общаться с магазином.

Есть уже даже реализации подключения к магазину на WooCommerce для Android. Например, приложение WooCommerce Mobile Assistant, которое можно установить с Play Market.

**UPDATE**

Тот же eMagicOne сделал Anroid приложения для PrestaShop, Magento, OpenCart, MijoShop, VirtueMart.