# Стандарты кодирования WordPress для phpStorm под Windows

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

Соблюдение стандартов кодирования WordPress часто требуется при групповой работе над проектом. Кроме того, выполненный по стандартам код повышает оценку претендента в глазах потенциального работодателя.

Сами стандарты описаны в Codex, но подключение их к Code Sniffer в phpStorm вызывает определённые сложности. Подключение требует установки и настройки нескольких пакетов, инструкции для которых разбросаны по разным сайтам.

Как выглядит полная последовательность действий по установке стандартов кодирования WordPress для phpStorm под Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Анализаторы кода такие, как **PHP Code Sniffer**, и стандарты кодирования такие, как **WordPress Coding Standards**, позволяют создавать современный, легко обновляемый код, избежать множества ошибок еще на стадии написания кода, и совершенно незаменимы при командной работе над проектом. Эти средства встроены в **phpStorm** — мощную современную среду разработки под php.

В то же время, у многих разработчиков возникают сложности при установке анализатора кода **PHP Code Sniffer** и правил оформления кода **WordPress Coding Standards** для него в **PhpStorm** под **Windows**. Ниже сведены воедино сведения по установке, собранные из разных источников.

Процедура подключения стандартов кодирования под Windows выглядит следующим образом.

### Установка PHP

Откройте страницу http://windows.php.net/download/ и выберите **32-х** или **64-х битный** файл в зависимости от битности архитектуры своей системы.

Еще есть варианты **TS** (Thread Safe) и **NTS** (Non Thread Safe). TS отличается тем, что позволяет PHP работать в нескольких потоках. Для простых приложений и взаимодействия с веб-сервером вполне подойдёт и NTS.

Распакуйте содержимое zip-архива, например, в `c:\php`.

Переименуйте файл `c:\php\php.ini-development` в `c:\php\php.ini`.

Найдите строку `;On windows:` и раскомментируйте после нее

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Для работы с WordPress понадобятся несколько расширений.

Найдите секцию `; Windows Extensions` и раскомментируйте строки

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Найдите строчку `;date.timezone =`, раскомментируйте и задайте вашу временную зону, например:

```
date.timezone = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

Наконец, добавьте строчки для отладчика **Xdebug** в самый конец.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=c:/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="ваш_пароль"
```

Сам отладчик в виде **dll**-файла надо скачать отсюда: https://xdebug.org/download.php и поместить в `c:\php\ext`. При скачивании выбрать ту же версию и разрядность PHP, что были выбраны при установке PHP.

### Установка PEAR

Сохраните страницу https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar как файл `c:\php\go-pear.phar`.

Запустите `cmd.exe` и введите команды

```
cd c:\php
php go-pear.phar
```

Ответьте на вопросы, приняв значения по умолчанию, нажимая `Enter`.

Добавьте пути в системный `PATH`, дважды щёлкнув на созданном в процессе установки файле `c:\php\PEAR_ENV.reg`.

### Установка PHP Code Sniffer

В папке `c:\php` появился файл `pear.bat`, с помощью которого надо установить PHP Code Sniffer.

Последняя версия PHP Code Sniffer —
 https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/download.

В `cmd.exe`выполните команду, указанную на странице с последней версией PHP Code Sniffer. На данный момент это:

```
pear install PHP_CodeSniffer-3.1.1
```

В папке `c:\php` появились новые файлы, в том числе `c:\php\phpcs.bat`.

### Установка Composer

Для дальнейшей установки понадобится **Composer**.

Загрузите файл https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe в папку `c:\php`.

Запустите файл `Composer-Setup.exe` и проведите установку по умолчанию.

Для активизации путей Composer надо перезапустить окно командной строки.

Composer добавлен, теперь вы можете его использовать для установки других пакетов.

### Установка PHP Code Sniffer в PhpStorm

Откройте в PhpStorm окно установок проекта (`Ctrl+Alt+S`) и выберите **Languages&Frameworks** → **PHP**.

Установите **PHP language level (7.1)**.

Нажмите на многоточие справа от **CLI Interpreter**.

В окне CLI Interpreters выберите файл **PHP executable** (`C:\php\php.exe`) и **Debugger extension**  (`C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14-x86_64.dll`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажмите **OK**.

В этом же окне установок выберите **Languages&Frameworks** → **PHP** → **Code Sniffer**.

Задайте к нему путь `C:\php\phpcs.bat`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажмите **OK**.

В этом же окне установок выберите **Editor** → **Inspections** → **PHP** → **PHP Code Sniffer validation** и требуемый **Coding standard**. На картинке ниже выбран PEAR.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажмите **ОК**.

Сейчас PHP Code Sniffer установлен, можно пользоваться командой меню `Code-Inspect Code`.

### Установка WordPress Coding Standards

В папке `c:\php` запустите команду (вот и пригодился Composer)

```
composer create-project wp-coding-standards/wpcs --no-dev
```

Появилась папка `c:\php\wpcs`.

### Добавление WordPress Coding Standards в PhpStorm

В окне установок выберите **Languages&Frameworks** → **PHP** → **Code Sniffer** и задайте к нему путь `C:\php\wpcs\vendor\bin\phpcs.bat`.

Можете нажать кнопку **Validate** рядом для проверки.

Обратите внимание — вы подключили теперь другой Code Sniffer, из папки `c:\php\wpcs`.

Нажмите **ОК**.

В этом же окне установок выберите **Editor** → **Inspections** → **PHP** → **PHP Code Sniffer validation** и требуемый Coding standard. Если в списке стандартов не видите WordPress, нажмите на кнопку обновления справа (кольцевые стрелочки).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Советую использовать **WordPress Extra** — самый строгий стандарт кодирования, за исключением **VIP**. Но VIP предназначен для специальных установок WordPress, и на обычных сайтах невозможно удовлетворить его требованиям. Подробнее здесь: https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards

На этом процесс установки закончен, и теперь вы можете создавать профессиональный код для своих сайтов на WordPress.