# PhpStorm - настройка php в интегрированном ubuntu в win10

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu, phpstorm, windows-10

Включил интегрированную Ubuntu в Win10, установил LAMP-стек, но столкнулся с проблемой - я не знаю как в шторм добавить интерпретатор PHP, установленный внутри Ubuntu. Как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите мой вопрос - ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737378/220220. Возможно, что-то пригодится

Comment: LAMP установлен внутри интегрированной Ubuntu внутри Windows 10, PhpStorm запускается из под Windows.

Comment: А вы по моей инструкции установите php на windows, и подключите его. Я так и работаю - сайты на сервере, интерпретатор локально.

Comment: Такое себе удовольствие, я считаю что среда должна быть цельная.

Comment: Вам работающий вариант нужен или удовольствие? Все работает прекрасно, проблем в отладке нет. Работает быстрее, чем по удаленному доступу. Но есть сильно хочется, то можно и удалённый php включить: http://take.ms/z8ktH

Comment: А, я наконец понял что вы имели в виду под установкой интерпретатора под Windows. Если у меня не получится настроить как я хочу, то так и сделаю, выбора-то все равно нет. Просто у php есть функции, которые на работают в окошках, например ветвление процессов. В любом случае спасибо за ответ, он был слишком прост и я не додумался до этого сразу :)

Comment: А в чем проблема включить remote, как я показал на картинке? Вы же убунту видите как сервер?

Answer (score 0):

**Settings->Languages->PHP** видим поле **Interpreter,** жмем три точки рядом, в открывшемся окне жмем **+**, в выпадающем списке выбираем **/usr/bin/php**

Comment: В Windows нет /usr/bin/php

Comment: @AccessDenied зато в убунте должно быть

Comment: @AccessDenied сама ФС убунты лежит по пути C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Lxss\rootfs