# Вывод поста по пермалинку

Tags: wordpress

На главной странице есть список постов с превью и тд. И внизу каждого поста есть ссылка на него. Есть шаблон для постов, где помимо общего вида страниц есть секция, в которой и отображается содержимое поста. Так вот, проблема в том, что при клике по ссылке с главной, я всегда перехожу на последний опубликованный пост. В ссылке использую пермалинк. Как вот в шаблоне получить данные именно из него?
Код с главной:

```
<div class="offers owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <?php
        global $post;
        $tmp_post = $post;
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 999, 'offset'=> 0 );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <div class="offer item">
                <div class="offer-img-<?=$p; $p++;?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                <div class="offer-info">
                    <time><?php the_time('Y.m.d'); ?></time>
                    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    <p class="offer-desc"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    <img class="offer-dots" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/offer-dots.png" style="width: auto;" alt="border" />
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">more</a>
                    <p class="offer-desc-320">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php $post = $tmp_post; ?>
    </div>
```

Код из шаблона (именно секция поста):

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query($post->ID); ?>
<?php while  ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="news-post center">
    <div class="name-title">
        <img src="http://myexsite.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/news.png" alt="news" />
        <p class="section-title">NEWS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="offer-name"><?php the_date('Y.m.d'); ?> - <?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div class="offer-content">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
        <div class="offer-text"><p><?php the_content() ?></p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Какой ужас.. Какой  нафик сокращённый синтаксиис php, какие  прямо заявленные урлы и тексты в шаблонах. Откуда это хлам? Выкинуть всё нафик и посмотреть как что сделано в нормальных темах. В родных или в любой из оф каталога. См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/763199

Comment: урлы и тексты поменяю потом, суть не в этом сейчас. Просто хочу знать, как вывести содержимое поста, исходя из его ссылки. Может тут указать что-то?   <?php $the_query = new WP_Query($post->ID); ?>

Comment: Ты б определся для начала  что тебе нужно - содержимое или ссылку (пермалинк). `get_permalink()` и даёт ссылку на запись  `the_content()` выводит пост

Comment: Мне нужно при клике на ссылку (more - подробнее о посте) получать на странице , на которую я перехожу, содержимое поста (заголовок, дата, картинка, и тд). Но я при переходе всегда получаю последний созданный пост, а мне нужно получать именно тот пост, который в ссылке.

Comment: Вот  выкинь этот хлам и посмотри в нормальных темах.

Comment: Уже разобрался. Просто убрал wp_query и все заработало. Спасибо за уделенное время

Comment: Поскольку в permalink ошибки быть не может, следует предположить, что на сайте используется самопальная тема с ошибками в шаблонах, например, single.php. Поддержу @SeVlad - изучайте официальные темы, ставьте любую на сайт, делайте от неё дочернюю, и в ней проводите свои изменения. Сэкономите кучу времени и быстрее освоите WordPress.

Comment: У вас WP_Query(), например, написан абы как. Почитайте документацию https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query

Comment: Я знаю, что тема самопальная и вообще не адаптирована под wp. Я ее делал, как статическую страницу с такими же статическими подстраницами, при этом не имея каких-то конкретных указаний на будущий функционал, чисто оболочка. Но потом поступило задание натянуть эту "красоту" на wp и я вот пытаюсь, ибо нахожусь на стажировке, и типа должен научиться всему, и конечно же, сам. Поэтому возникают такие вот конфузы.

Comment: Попробуйте все уже уйти в дочернюю тему от какой-то стандартной темы из репозитория. Переход потребует некоторого времени, но зато потом намного легче будет вносить правки.

Comment: И если уж хотите учиться, пишите код по стандартам WordPress https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards. Установите phpStorm и Code Sniffer https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737378/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-wordpress-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-phpstorm-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-windows/737379#737379 это вам существенно облегчит разработку

Comment: Если проблема только в ссылке, то нужно менять <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">more</a>, например попробуй <?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>