# Почему не работает поддержка синтаксиса wordpress в phpstorm?

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

Подключил плагин wordpress, далее включил поддержку wordpress в настройках

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезапустил шторм, но автокомплит не заработал.

Что я забыл?

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Все работает. Посмотрите у меня в вопросах про php code sniffer для WordPress.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737378/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-wordpress-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-phpstorm-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-windows

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, только вы описали инструкцию для виндовс - это во-первых. А во-вторых, мне просто нужно подсветить синтаксис wordpress для начала, так как я новичок в этой теме.

Comment: Во-первых, как я могу догадаться, что у вас не Windows?

Comment: Извините, это мой косяк))

Comment: Вы вопрос-то свой читали? Попробуйте перейти по ссылке. А вообще-то картинки надо вставлять в вопрос картинками.

Comment: Изменил шапку, просто на других форумах ссылка работает, а тут нет. Буду знать в дальнейшем.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74623/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-serii).

Comment: Я уже написал в чате

Comment: Короче я нашел решение. Что я делал до сих пор. В убунту я в группу своего пользователя добавли группу www-data. И выходило, что для папки с сайтом группа была user.

Answer (score 1):

Короче я нашел решение. Что я делал до сих пор. В убунту я в группу своего пользователя добавли группу www-data. И выходило, что для папки с сайтом группа была user.
Теперь я решил изменить подход, добавил своего пользователя в группу www-data. Создал новый проект и теперь автокомплит wordpress заработал. 
Думаю, что в этом была вся проблема.

Comment: А что, ваш пользователь не мог читать файлы в папке wp-includes? Вы поясните ответ с указанием конкрентных прав доступа папок и файлов проекта, их собственника. Пока что складывается впечатление, что дело было не в этом.

Comment: У меня пользователь serii, а права были serii:serii, своего пользователя я добавил в группу www-data:www-data

Comment: У меня пользователь serii, а права были serii:serii, своего пользователя я добавил в группу www-data:www-data
Права на папку с файлами были 755. 
Я не знаю как получилось, но мне пришло в голову мысль, что нунжо задать владельца для файлов www-data. 
Раньше я так всегда и делал, но тогда еще не изучал wordpress. 
Потом пришлось переустанавливать систему и опять возиться с правами доступа. Вот тогда на форумах мне и повстречалась информация, что нунжно добавить группу www-data в группу пользователя. Я так и сделал, и до сих пор проблем не было.

Comment: По поводу группы для папки с сайтом в инете бытует много холивара, я для себя так и нашел правильного и однозначного ответа. 
Плохо, что нет нормальной официальной инструкции, как сделать то или иное действие в линукс. Каждый делает по-своему. 
Вот, допустим в html или css все правила уже переопределены, там даже консорциум есть, а линукс - это свободная среда, где каждый делает то, что он хочет. И вот с этой свободой и приходиться мучаться. 
Или я не прав?
Если не так, то поправьте меня.

Comment: Владелец папки сайта и всех подпапок должен быть тот, под кем выполняется php. В Apache это www-data:www-data. Права на папки должны быть 755, на файлы 644.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли. Проблема практически решена. Вот создал второй проект, все отлично работает.