# Не прогружаются картинки товаров при импорте WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я импортирую товары в WooCommerce, но часть изображений будто не прогружается (их превью) http://prntscr.com/hqdu02. Почему так может происходить? То есть в карточке товара из админки они есть, а вот в на сайте они не грузятся (во фронте).

Comment: Не думаю, что вам тут кто-то с этим поможет. Ибо интернет-магазин на WP - это.... ну, как минимум непрофессионально, небезопасно, неудобно и еще много чего. И навряд ли такие люди здесь отвечают, если они вообще есть =) ИМХО.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin это не комментарий, а полная шкатулка глупостей. Начиная от нелепых представлениях о WP, незнании долей рынка Интернет-магазинов, и заканчивая предположением об отвечающих.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin вы хоть просмотрите вопросы по меткам WordPress и WooCommerce, прежде чем делать глубокомысленные заявления)

Comment: @KAGGDesign и тем не менее, ни одного ответа или какого-либо другого комментария. Долю рынка WordPress я знаю. в топ-10 сайтов WooCommerce 10%, в топ-100 – 17%, топ-миллионе – 21%, а во всем интернете – 42%. Что говорит о том, что чем менее популярен магазин, тем чаще он использует WooCommerce. Количество - не показатель. Показатель то что на собеседование Backend-разработчика приходят школьники, которые сумели установить тему с парой плагинов, сделали страницу с дизайном 0-х годов и серьезно предъявляют это как портфолио.

Comment: @KAGGDesign говорить о Wordpress можно много, так же как и о Joomla с её тоже огромной долей рынка, но это не меняет факта того что это две огромных черных дыры в безопасности и если у вас нет возможности обновлять все в тот же день как выходят обновления, то сайт загнется от вирусов за пол года. Видел я вирусные скрипты где четко прописано - если WP - делать одно, если Joomla - делать другое. Ни у каких других систем нет такой проблемы с безопасностью)

Comment: @KAGGDesign за нас с вами уже давно эту тему обсуждали сотни раз. Вон, почитайте на хабре [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/251257/) и [опровержение](https://habrahabr.ru/post/251315/) и комментарии к ним...и рейтинг их посмотрите. Думаю не стоит сомневаться что на хабре сидят в основном довольно компетентные люди, мне до многих из них как раком до китая, но абсолютное большинство считает так что если ты не умеешь делать сайты - делай на вордпрессе, умеешь - делай на чем-то еще. Не исключаю возможности заработать на продаже плагинов школьникам, ведь аудитория WP - миллионы.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin а почему должны быть ответы или комментарии на каждый вопрос? Этот вопрос плохо сформулирован, потому на него и не отвечают. Здесь никто никому ничего не должен. Другие вопросы по меткам WP и WC посмотрите. Но вы же не хотите смотреть, вам хочется сделать вывод о WordPress в целом на основании одного неотвеченного вопроса на SO.

Comment: @VladimirNovopashin здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/702220/220220 почитайте, пройдите по ссылкам, расталдыкните свой кругозор. И объясните себе, почему вы умнее Mercedes-Benz и SAP. Мне ничего объяснять не надо )