# Что такое wordpress и зачем он нужен?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

По началу думал что сперва верстальщик делает основу(html, css, js) сайта(блога, магазина) передает его заказчику а тот в свою очередь не зная о веб технологиях пользуясь вордпрессом наполняет его контентом(статьями или товарами). Правильно ли я понимаю? Или это просто конструктор сайтов? Стоит ли его учить фронтендщику? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [WordPress — система управления содержимым сайта с открытым исходным кодом; написана на PHP; сервер базы данных — MySQL; выпущена под лицензией GNU GPL версии 2. Сфера применения — от блогов до достаточно сложных новостных ресурсов и интернет-магазинов.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/702220/220220

Comment: @Grundy ну вот я и дал ссылку на свой ответ в комментарии ))

Comment: @KAGGDesign, ссылки мало, надо в любом случае закрывать: либо как дубликат, либо как и тот вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy проголосовал уже за закрытие